# Definition of zerovalent vertex in a tree

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

In the paper "Recurrence relations for the number of labeled structures on a finite set" by Blatter and Specker the authors speak of univalent, zerovalent and multivalent points of a tree.

It seems to me that a univalent point is a leaf of the tree. But the term "zerovalent point" doesn't make sense to me. And there is also the notion of  multivalent ("not univalent" seems natural).

I could not find a definition of these terms. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Intuitively it sounds like "zerovalent" ought to mean the single vertex in a tree with exactly one vertex. Would that make sense in the context?

Comment: What kind of trees? Are they rooted trees? Perhaps the article [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) may help you.